# Python serial port status

Tags: python, serial-port

How do you know the status of a serial port in Python prior to opening the serial port?

I know I can use the following code below, to determine its status, but this required the port to be already open.

```
if self.ser.isOpen():
```

The reason I ask, is sometimes when I execute my code I get a serial exception stating that the port is already open, in this case, I want to know before hand and try to close it before opening it.

Comment: maybe I should query something like python -m serial.tools.list_ports

Comment: I don't know much about serial ports, but couldn't you just `try` and `catch` open port error?

Comment: I am using the following to wait, but think there is a better way
 except:
 print 'serial port not available, please ensure it is plugged in'
 time.sleep(10)
 try:
  self.ser.open()
  time.sleep(5)
 except:
  print 'Will keep waiting'

Comment: Instead, you could ensure that you always close the port after an operation by wrapping all operations in `with contextlib.closing(self.ser)`

Comment: how do you recommend I close the serial port after CTRL+C closing my script, bare in mind I have 1 thread in deamon mode runing the serial listen

Comment: Doesn't your OS close the port if you exit the process?

Comment: sometimes it doesn't so i unplug the serial cable off and then back on, any recommendation please

Comment: The purpose of *open()* is to control access to a file/device.  If the file/device has not yet been opened by you, then you don't deserve access, especially when another process has already opened that file for exclusive access.  Instead of focusing on what you want, consider why the OS has to maintain security for a user who might have malicious intents.

Comment: Thanks, I think it has to do with how my script cleans up after itself when I press the CTR+C

Comment: I've seen slow/delayed re-opens of the serial port in Linux even after the serial port was properly closed as the program exited.  The fix I found for slow/delayed re-opens was to flush the serial port, i.e. `tcflush(sfd, TCIOFLUSH)`before closing the serial port.  Don't know about scripts, but a program can regain control after a Ctrl+C if the program sets up a signal handler for SIGINT.  Another possibility is to acquire/open the serial port in a master script, and then give the serial port as *stdin* & *stdout* to the invoked script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have mentioned you know the status of the port by using `isOpen()`. This will return a bool value of either `True` or `False`.

When you declare a serial port initially for example:
`ser.serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')` the port is opened by default. You could either close the serial port using `ser.close()` and check the status of the serial port using `ser.isOpen()`.

Hope [this](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#testing-ports) helps you more.